# Better way to get R/Java (MOA) clustering algorithms results and process them with python

Tags: java, python, r, cluster-analysis, integration

I have always used Python for clustering, but recently I came across a situation in which I need the implementations of both **CluStream** and **DenStream** (stream clustering algorithms), available in **R** and **Java** (there are some implementations in Python from the community but I already tried them and they do no work).

The thing is that I **have to compare many clustering algorithms written in Python**, and as a prev stage I was using the well known **scikit learn data sets** (to show how algorithms handle non-globular clusters - of course then I will use time series data).

Now, I wanna know if **the proper way to try those R/Java algorithms and compute a metric coded in Python** ([DBCV](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/blob/master/hdbscan/validity.py)) with the R/Java clustering results ....

**--> So, summing up, I need to compare many algorithms (coded in Python and R/Java) using the same data sets (which I figured could be persisted into csv files) and computing the same validity metric (Python).**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**: the solution I came across is the following:

- Generate the toy data sets with sklearn and persist them into csv files
- Use the different clustering algorithms with those data sets and persist also the clustering results into csv files (it does not matter which programming language it's used)
- Develop another app which:

  - takes the clustering solutions stored in the cvs files
  - computes the metric and shows the results

PLEASE let me know if you find a better solution!

---

**Notes**:

- This R package is the one i wanna try: [streamMOA](https://github.com/mhahsler/streamMOA)
- I do not know anything about R and I have worked with Java before (what implementation I choose depends on the better approach regarding the integration with Python)

Comment: check [`rpy2`](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. MOA is a Java software. There is no good reason to use it via R unless you are already in the R ecosystem (which you aren't).
2. You can write the data to CSV and load it in whatever tool you like
3. These data sets are not streams. They lack all the difficulties and challenges of streams - a simple subsample will be enough to identify the clustering structure. **Conclusions drawn from this data are useless.** Use real data streams, not synthetic data with *no* sequential order to it.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes, after some rest I noticed I could persist the datasets into csv files, and I did it. Now, as I have to compare the results using a metric coded in Python, I will have to decide what to do with the mentioned implementations (R vs Java). Finally, just wanted to mention that these toy datasets will be used to show that the algorithm can handle non globular clusters; then, I will use real streams. Thanks!